# Docker bind mount to environment variable (in ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I have two paths. One to take templates from and one to generate documents in.
Deploying this on Docker works fine (the App starts, works and gives no warnings), bind mount creates these 2 directories on my local machine, but doesn't seem to use them, or even create them? on the container.

Here is what I tried:

1) Specified paths in AppSettings.json (this is my configuration without Docker, it will be overridden below in docker-compose file)

```
  "RootDirectoryForDocuments": {
    "DocumentsRoot": "TestDocumentsDir",
    "TemplatesRoot": "TestTemplatesDir"
  }
```

2) Created Docker Compose File. Here first I'm giving the paths as environment variables and then trying to make the container use them in volumes section:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    hraapi: 
        build: ../Hra.Api
        environment:
            - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
            - ENV_RootDirectoryForDocuments_DocumentsRoot="/app/GeneratedDocs"
            - ENV_RootDirectoryForDocuments_TemplatesRoot="/app/Templates"

        image: user/hra.api:v1.0
        container_name: hra.api
        ports:
            - "5000:80"
        depends_on:
            - hradb
        volumes:
            - C:/Users/User/Desktop/GeneratedDocs:/app/GeneratedDocs
            - C:/Users/User/Desktop/Templates:/app/Templates
```

When I run this DockerCompose it automatically creates these 2 Folders on my Desktop. However, I was hoping it would create and use them in the Container as well.
I tried a lot to find how ASP.NET Core containers are structured, in order to use an already existing path there but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, I can't comment yet, but here might be solution to your "container hierarchy" problem:

Do this docker works on your local machine? You can log into the working docker container using the id of the container and check exactly what's happening inside on the filesystem.
First, get the docker id:

```
#> docker ps
```

Then, using the id (it will look like: ka7859adgfa59)

```
#> docker exec -it ka7859adgfa59 /bin/bash
```

you can get inside the container with bash shell.

The "volumes:" part uses the Short Syntax, which should create those folders inside if they are not there already [SHORT SYNTAX](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#short-syntax-3)

Comment: Thank you @ashantiel. Exploring the container file structure with docker exec -it hra.api /bin/bash really helped. Problem is that I was using a path like "DocumentsRoot\Something". C# with resharper let me mess around with back or forward slashes, but in docker compose  this path wasn't escaped. So it created a folder named literally "DocumentsRoot\Something".